# Transformation of random variable?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

i know that if we have a random variable having standard normal distribution (mean = 0 and var = 1) then its square is chi-square distribution with 1 degree of freedom. My question is " does the same thing applies if the random variable is having normal distribution (mean = non-zero and var = other than 1).

Comment: If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then $\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. Hence the random variable
$$ \frac{1}{\sigma^2} (X^2 - 2 \mu X + \mu^2) \sim \chi_2. $$
So in some sense $X^2 - 2 \mu X \sim \sigma^2 \chi_2 - \mu^2$, but I don't think you can do much better (in particular because $X$ and $X^2$ are highly correlated).

Comment: if $Z$ is standard normal random variable then $Z^2$ is chi-square random variable with 1 degree of freedom. My doubt is what will be $Z^2$, if $Z$ is simply normal random variable ( note that it is not standard normal).

Comment: It is not going to be a chi-quare. I can show you how to compute the corresponding density if you want.

Comment: No, the chi-square distribution is defined for centered-reduced variables. Notice that $(\sigma X+\mu)^2=\sigma^2X^2+2\sigma\mu X+\mu^2$, so that the resulting distribution depends on the sum of a chi-square and a normal law, plus a shift. Hence it is the result of the convolution of a chi-square and a Gaussian.

Comment: If it is not chi-square then what will it be?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not entirely sure about your convolution assertion, because $X$ and $X^2$ are correlated so the law of their sum is not in general given by the convolution.

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois - Is there a reason you use $\chi_2$ rather than $\chi_1^2$?

Comment: Absolutely not, this is the same distribution, sorry about that (I can't edit anymore).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi$ be a test function. We compute
$$ \mathbb{E}[\phi(X^2)]$$
for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. This gives
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[\phi(X^2)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x^2) \frac{e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} dx \\
\qquad \qquad \qquad = 2 \int_0^{\infty} \phi(y) \frac{e^{-\frac{(\sqrt{y}-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{2 \sqrt{y} \sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} dy 
\end{equation}
where I split the integral into $\mathbb{R}_-$ and $\mathbb{R}_+$ and perform the change of variable $y = x^2$ in both integrals.
Since this is valid for all test function, we can identify the density of $X^2$ for $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$. It is given, on $\mathbb{R}_+$ by
$$ f(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{y 2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(\sqrt{y}-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}. $$
Notice that for $\mu = 0$, $\sigma^2 = 1$ you recover indeed the $\chi^2_1$ distribution.

Comment: i understood the derivation. But my doubt is still not cleared. Can you fill in the blank below.     If Z is normal random distributed then distribution of Z^2 is _____________.

Comment: Just found this, which might help ! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi_distribution